# Доступ к модели Django

Tags: django, django-orm

есть две модели (пример):

```
class Posts(model.Model):
    pass

class Statistics(model.Model):
    post = model.ForeignKey(Post)
    count = model.IntegerField()
```

Есть ли такая возможность достать на пример с модели `Posts` значение из `Statistics.count`?

Comment: Можно. Но с какой именно из множества моделей `Statistics`? Для первой: `post.statistics_set.first().count`.

Comment: @nomnoms12 все сработало, напишите ответ что б я его подтвердил!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К одному экземпляру модели `Posts` может быть привязано несколько экземпляров модели `Statistics`, поэтому непонятно, из какой именно нужно брать информацию.

Если Вы хотите, чтобы у одной записи была только одна статистика, то используйте [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield), вместо `ForeignKey`.

***Пример:***

```py
class Post(model.Model):  # Posts -> Post
    pass


class Statistics(model.Model):
    post = model.OneToOneField(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    count = model.IntegerField()
```

Получить `count` можно так:

```py
post.statistics.count
```

---

Если же оставить текущие модели, то получить `count` из первого привязанного экземпляра `Statistics` можно так:

```py
post.statistics_set.first().count
```

---

**P.S.:** Лучше называть модели в единственном числе.